# PHP regular expression with nth occurrence

Tags: php, preg-match

Here's a string:

**n%3A171717%2Cn%3A%747474%2Cn%3A555666%2Cn%3A1234567&bbn=555666**

From this string how can I extract *1234567* ? Need a good logic / syntax.

I guess preg_match would be a better option than explode function in PHP.

It's about a PHP script that extracts data. The numbers can vary and the occurrence of numbers can vary as well only %2Cn%3A will always be there in front of the numbers.the end will always have a **&bbn=anyNumber**.

Comment: /%2Cn%3A(\d+)&/ - https://www.regex101.com/r/mQ5dH4/1

Comment: "I guess preg_match would be a better option than explode function in PHP." ...why is that?

Comment: For starters: `echo urldecode('n%3A171717%2Cn%3A%747474%2Cn%3A555666%2Cn%3A1234567&bbn=555666');`

Comment: You want the last value always? Maybe `.*n%3A(.+)&bbn`? If `&bbn=anyNumber` is always the ending and `n%3A` always precedes each value.

Comment: @chris85 I need the value right before &bbn

Comment: Yea... and that doesn't work that way? https://regex101.com/r/rW1nJ3/1 I also don't see why explode wouldn't work though..

Comment: Where is this coming from?  Much better ways to do it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver anything in a one line PHP is ok for me.

Comment: @chris85 we can use explode but that would be a bit lengthy, I think.

Comment: you can do this too /(\d+)(?=&bbn)/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like part of an encoded URL so there's bound to be better ways to do it, but `urldecoded()` your string looks like:

> n:171717,n:t7474,n:555666,n:1234567&bbn=555666

So:

```
preg_match_all('/n:(\d+)/', urldecode($string), $matches);
echo array_pop($matches[1]);
```

Parenthesized matches are in `$matches[1]` so just `array_pop()` to get the last element.

If `&bbn=` can be anywhere (except for at the beginning) then:

```
preg_match('/n:(\d+)&bbn=/', urldecode($string), $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: he wants *1234567* before &bbn,

Comment: @abracadaver you are right when you say there are many ways of doing this and this is an encoded url but a one liner regular expression would be very helpful.

Comment: You can't do it in one line because you have to retrieve something from the matches.

Comment: @izk: That's exactly what it does unless you move `&bbn` around somewhere else.

Comment: @AbraCadaver apologies misread the preg_match. Nice solution !

Answer (score 1):

> only %2Cn%3A will always be there in front of the numbers

urldecoded equivalent of `%2Cn%3A` is `,n:`.
The last "enclosing boundary" `&bbn` remains as is.
`preg_match` function will do the job:

```
preg_match("/(?<=,n:)\d+(?=&bbn)/", urldecode("n%3A171717%2Cn%3A%747474%2Cn%3A555666%2Cn%3A1234567&bbn=555666"), $m);

print_r($m[0]);  // "1234567"
```